# How to save a texture or texture region to a file in libgdx?

Tags: opengl-es, textures, libgdx

well that is pretty much it, I want to modify some textures in libgdx at run time an be able to save them to a file as .png, but I have no idea how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you "modifying" the textures?  (On screen, or in the actual underlying texture data?)

Comment: well with pixmaps I just draw them to the texture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `Pixmap` use the `getPixels` method to get the pixel data, convert that to a `byte[]` and then follow the example at this libGDX forum post: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=8358#p8358

The post talks about using `ScreenUtils` to scrape the screen and get an array of pixels.  Everything after that point should be the same for you.

I've had success with this code, but it does generate very inefficient PNG files.  I used pngcrush to consolidate them offline.

Comment: can you post some lines of code? Only needed the conversion from TextureRegion to byte[]